# Getting the original matrix from the projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, projection-matrices

If I have the projection matrix of $X$,
$$
P = X\,{(X^TX)}^{-1} X^T, 
$$
how can I recover $X$ by only knowing $P$?
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You cannot recover exactly $X$ (indeed, any $\lambda X$ with $\lambda \neq 0$ would lead to the same projection matrix), but you can get the one-dimensional subspace generated by $X$, which is just the image of $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying $\,P$ by $X\,$ yields
$$\eqalign{
PX &= X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX \;\doteq\; X \\
}$$
Therefore, given any random matrix $A:\quad X=PA$

$\sf Proof:$
$$\eqalign{
PX &= P\left(PA\right) \,=\, PA \;\doteq\; X \quad \\
}$$
So you can certainly use $P$ to calculate $X,\,$ however the solution isn't **unique**

because every $A$ matrix leads to a different $X$.